# Qt 4.8.4 - Build machine is 10.8 with Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, build, qt4.8

Given my build machine is machine is OS X 10.8 with Xcode 4.6 and my Qt version is 4.8.4:

Can I build Qt from source to support 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8? I assume with BASE SDK of 10.6?

or is it possible only under this configuration? 10.6 SDK isn't even in the /Developer tree of the new XCode.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean you want to build on your machine so it's supported from 10.6 upwards?

Comment: yes. build on 10.8 - run my .app on 10.6 and up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> In general, Qt supports building on one Mac OS X version and deploying on all others, both forward and backwards. You can build on 10.4 Tiger and run the same binary on 10.5 and up.
>   [Qt Docs: Developing on Mac.](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/developing-on-mac.html#deployment-compile-once-deploy-everywhere)

As a caveat, I've done it before and it does work but you will be best off building and testing on each of the versions of OS X you're deploying on for sanity purposes. In general, it's perfectly fine but there can occasionally be the odd part where it won't work.